# Mac os x ipfw forward from ip:port to ip:port

Tags: ipfw

I want when on my local machine redirect from 192.168.64.88 port 80 to localhost port 9790. How can I do it with ipfw rule?

Comment: Poor man's solution would be to use `http://localhost:9790` in the browser. I assume this is not an option for you?

Comment: It is not an option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 192.168.64.88 alias
sudo ipfw add fwd 127.0.0.1,9790 tcp from me to 192.168.64.88 dst-port 80
```

After a restart you have to run this commands again.

Comment: You can define a launchd entry to automatically execute these commands on a reboot.

Comment: or you could put it in your `~/.bash_profile` but that would only work if you live in the terminal

Comment: Unfortunately ipfw has been deprecated. How to achieve the same using pfctl tool?