# Any way to transparantly redirect outbound traffic to a particular IP:port on OS X?

Tags: macos, network, firewall

OS: Yosemite
Basically I am looking for something similar to [Mac os x ipfw forward from ip:port to ip:port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/mac-os-x-ipfw-forward-from-ipport-to-ipport) but since there is no ipfw on Yosemite is there a way to do this trick using pfctl or something like that?